# DataMaps js problem using async functions

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, d3.js, datamaps

I've created a script that gets data from API, format the data and use it using DataMaps http://datamaps.github.io/.

In my .js file i can simply call:

```
var map = new Datamap({element: document.getElementById('container')});
```

And it will render the map in selected div.
 The problem is that if i use it inside async function to get the data from an API and render the map filled with API's data I get this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'select' of undefined
    at Datamap.drawSubunits (datamaps.all.js:184)
    at draw (datamaps.all.js:789)
    at Datamap.draw (datamaps.all.js:768)
    at new Datamap (datamaps.all.js:730)
...
```

I even get this error if i just call the map this way inside the async function, so the data is not the problem:

```
async function fetchData() {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/countries?yesterday=&sort=');
        const data = await (response.json());
        var map = new Datamap({element: document.getElementById('container')});
        return data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
fetchData();
```

If I put **var map = new Datamap({element: document.getElementById('container')});** outside the function it works. 
I have no clue about it.

Any help would be appreciated. 
First post and english is not my main language.

Answer (score 0):

judging by mistake, you use the nonexistent variable 'select' or an empty variable. maybe I was wrong in spelling my English level is not so good